# Proving $0.1 ≤ P(AB) ≤ 0.4$ while knowing $P(A)$ and $P(B)$, but not making any further assumptions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The problem I'm stuck on is:

> Assume that $P(A) = 0.4$ and $P(B) = 0.7$. Making no further assumptions on $A$ and $B$, prove that $P(AB)$ satisfies $0.1 ≤ P(AB) ≤ 0.4$.

This would be easy if we could assume that $P(AB)$ was actually between the two values, because then I could prove the independence of $A$ and $B$, and solve from there.  The problem is, I don't think I can make that assumption.

I'm really at a loss here, so any direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**
$$P(A\cap B) \le P(A)\\
P(A\cup B) \le 1$$
Now use inclusion-exclusion principle and it's right in front of you:
$$P(A) + P(B) - 1 \le P(A\cap B) \le P(A)$$

Comment: Oh I didn't think about inclusion-exclusion! Thanks!

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: @user181928 If this solved you question, please mark it as answered. Else feel free to ask for further clarification.